# MVC architecture development

Tags: apache-flex, model-view-controller, flex4.5

I have a mobile application that I want to try and reorganize so that it's easier to read and update and follows better practice.

I want to implement an MVC pattern, but I'm getting a little tripped up on getting there. I'm just hoping for some help with rebuilding the architecture.

Here's the outline of my application:

Level1) MainView has a column of 5 buttons that when clicked lead to View1, View2, View3, View4 or View5.

Level2) Each of these views is the same: a list, but each is populated with different data. Selecting an item brings the user to another set of views SubView1 - 20. that each are again populated with a list.

Level3) However, any selection made on a List in a SubView leads to a view that is always the same for all selection paths - but is populated with different data. Basically a button, another list, a text input and a textarea.

From what I gather, I should be able to use a lot less files and achieve something of the same result:

The model being a single class for data? The controller being a class or that controls the business logic, and a view that calls the controller?

Any suggestions, ideas and points in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you'll be doing this in Flex4 and incorporate MVC pattern to some extent while doing so.

Have you looked into Cairngorm?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairngorm_%28Flex_framework%29

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I haven't looked at too many frameworks, I've heard people talking about Cairngorm on this website and stuff, but the only one I've really looked into is Robotlegs (which I'm keen to try).
Right now, I don't have any framework and I just have a lot of views with hard-coded data, and I'd like to be able to update one or two dbs instead of each view manually every time I change some data...